# Passing a single variable from an array through an input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am pulling addresses out of a mysql database. The addresses are displayed in a form, through an array, as a list with a (hidden) input and a (submit) input attached to each address. The intension is that a user can click on the (submit) input by the address they want to view and the (hidden) input would pass the ID (as_id).

What I coded works to a point. It displays the addresses and an input at each address.

What does not work is that once a (submit) is clicked for the selected address it passes " " no matter which (submit) input is chosen.

I’ve read about turning the input into an array with “[]” after the “name”. I playsed with that for a while. I got a “strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array” error and got lost for a few hours on that. I gave it up; didn’t think I was going in the right direction.

```
`enter code here`
echo "<div class='searchres'>";

echo "<form name='choose' method='post' id='choose' action='asset_search.php'>";

echo "<table>";

while ($asset_info = mysql_fetch_array($search_rs)) {

array_pop($asset_info);

        echo "<tr>";

          echo "<td width='400px'>";

          echo $asset_info['as_id'] . " ";

          echo $asset_info['as_st_number'] . " ";   

          echo $asset_info['as_st_dir'] . " ";

                echo $asset_info['as_st_name'] . " ";

          echo $asset_info['as_st_desig'] . " ";

          echo $asset_info['as_unit_num'] . " ";

          echo $asset_info['as_city'] . " ";

          echo "<br />";

          echo "</td>";

          echo "<td>";

          echo "<input name='hide' type='hidden' value='" . htmlspecialchars($asset_info
                ['as_id']) . "'>";

          echo "<input name='search' type='submit' id='search' value='View Property'>";

}

                echo "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

echo "</form>";

echo "</div>";
```

I only need to pass the as_id, not the whole array. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to check this line:

```
echo "<input name='hide' type='hidden' value='" . htmlspecialchars($asset_info['as_id']) . "'>";
```

You use the name `hide`, this should be `hide[]` then you should check for the value of `$_POST['hide']`.

Edited:
But there is something else wrong with your code. You use one form for all addresses, with the same button for all addresses. You need to make a different form tag for each address. In that case you do not need to put [] behind the input name, although I would pick another name than 'hide'. Put the whole form in the while loop.

Comment: The [] is what I looked at for a couple of hours. I get “Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:….dbc.php on line 131”. Line 131 has nothing to do with this “Post”. It is part of the “Search” criteria which gave me the results for the array. That is why it lost me. I cannot follow where the code is going. I also get a “Notice: Array to string conversion in C:….asset_search.php on line 72” when I use the []. Line 72 just echo’s the results of the post.

Comment: Sorry. The first error is on an "include" page. Line 131 dbc.php is filtering my "Post". I will have to look into that further.

Comment: what does the generated html look like for this input entry? On another note I think your table is a little off. The } at the bottom should be below the /tr a few lines lower.

Comment: I figured out the strip_tags() error. I had the filter ignor the post if it was not an array >if (!is_array($data))<. Once I changed that my output is "Array"

Comment: RST - What do mean by "generated html" for this input entry? I moved the } down below the /tr. No change.

Comment: when you look at the source of the page using FireFox for example.

Comment: RST - When I view source since most of the code is in php it does not show. Only what I have in plan html shows.

Comment: RST- That did it. I moved the form into the loop and changed the form name with a number each loop (choose($co))($co = $co + 1). Thanks for the help.(I also changed the input name).